# How can I remove the 'already played' moves from the 'available moves' list?

Tags: c#

```
            List<int> boardmove = new List<int>();
            boardmove.Add(0);
            boardmove.Add(1);
            boardmove.Add(2);
            boardmove.Add(3);
            boardmove.Add(4);
            boardmove.Add(5);
            boardmove.Add(6);
            boardmove.Add(7);
            boardmove.Add(8);

            int rand = rnd.Next(1, count);

            int num_one = boardmove[rand];

            boardmove.RemoveAt(num_one);

            count--;
```

I  am trying to implement a computer player for my tic tac toe game. I am  using a list to move the computer player, I want to index in the list and then remove the value I have selected. I want to select a unique value from the list each time.

```
            List<int> boardmove = new List<int>();
            boardmove.Add(0);
            boardmove.Add(1);
            boardmove.Add(2);
            boardmove.Add(3);
            boardmove.Add(4);
            boardmove.Add(5);
            boardmove.Add(6);
            boardmove.Add(7);
            boardmove.Add(8);

            int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(0, boardmove.Count);

            int selectedMove= boardmove[selectedIndex];
            Console.WriteLine(selectedMove);

            boardmove.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
            Console.WriteLine(selectedIndex);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but you want to make a few small changes:

```
int rand = rnd.Next(1, count);
```

Let's use more descriptive variable names, following camel-casing conventions, and remember that list indexing starts at zero. We don't need a separate count variable because the `List<T>` has one built-in:

```
int selectedIndex = random.Next(0, boardMove.Count);
```

Then

```
int num_one = boardmove[rand];
```

becomes:

```
int selectedMove = boardMove[selectedIndex];
```

And finally, here we're trying to remove from an indexed location, but passing a value from that index instead of the index itself.

```
boardmove.RemoveAt(num_one);
```

We can fix that as either:

```
boardMove.Remove(selectedMove);
```

or (slightly faster)

```
boardMove.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
```

Just make sure you're matching apples to apples. Methods that want an index should be passed an index. Methods that want a value should be passed a value.

---

Also, make sure you're not running this code back-to-back the way you've shown it here. I assumed you'd just snipped out the relevant bits for brevity, but just in case, you'll want your code to be in at least three parts:

```
// 1. Declare a member variable to hold your list of remaining moves,
//    so it can persist between turns. Prep its capacity to 9 entries.
List<int> boardMove = new List<int>(9);

// 2. Have a dedicated method to put stuff in order when starting a new game.
void StartGame() {
    // Erase any remaining moves left-over from last game.
    boardMove.Clear();

    // Prep the moves list with one of each move.
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        boardMove.Add(i);

    // Do other stuff like setting up the board / etc...
}

// 3. Have a function to choose a random move when you need one.
//    This just picks from the existing list, it doesn't make a new one.
int SelectRandomMove() {
    int selectedIndex = random.Next(0, boardMove.Count);
    int selectedMove = boardMove[selectedIndex];
    boardMove.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    return selectedMove;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            Random rnd = new Random();

        List<int> boardmove = new List<int>(9);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            boardmove.Add(i);

        while (gameOver==false)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter X spot (1-9): ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(1, boardmove.Count);

            int selectedMove= boardmove[selectedIndex];
            Console.WriteLine(selectedMove);

            boardmove.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
```

I have figured out my problem by moving my list initialization before my while loop

Comment: one final question about my game, the O's overwrite my X's on my board. I am unsure of how to compare X's to O's so they do not repeat themselves. also I do get the values of O's to be unique to the  list.

Comment: When X plays, remove their move selection (`num`) from `boardMove` so that space they chose is no longer eligible for O to pick. Also, please get in the habit of naming your variables with something meaningful. `num` tells us nothing about the variable except that it's a number — something we already know anyway because it's an `int`. Calling it `selectedMoveX` or `playerSelectedMove` in contrast to `selectedMoveO` or `opponentSelectedMove` makes your code much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Random rnd = new Random();

        List<int> boardmove = new List<int>(9);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            boardmove.Add(i);

        while (gameOver==false)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter X spot (1-9): ");
            int selectedMoveX= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(1, boardmove.Count);

            int selectedMoveO= boardmove[selectedIndex];

            boardmove.RemoveAt(selectedMoveX);
            boardmove.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

            switch (selectedMoveX)
```

this code works correctly I am posting so that I can help others. is there anyway I can make the X input more bulletproof.

Comment: Please consider editing your existing answer instead of posting a new one. If you want to ask a question about your X input, use the "Ask Question" button instead.